# Pandas how to compare the index or date_time is greater then for two rows in two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I compare the index or date_time is greater then another row in two different columns within a groupby?

How can I tell where `['mfe_long_return'] = 33.25` came before via index or time_stamp where `['mae_long_return '] = -15.00`

I also need to group by: `df.groupby(['date', 'buy_dom','_buy_aggression_pivot']` to select the `mfe_long_return` and `mae_long_return` within that group.

I tried something like:

```
df.loc[(df.groupby(['date', 'buy_dom','_buy_aggression_pivot',df['mfe_long_return'] > 0])['mfe_long_return'].transform('min') >= 29, 'date_time')] >= df.loc[(df.groupby(['date', 'buy_dom','_buy_aggression_pivot',df['mae_long_return'] < 0])['mae_long_return'].transform('min') <= -15, 'date_time')]
```

but get the error `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

I have a large dataframe, but for this comparison the minimum I need are the following columns:

```
|     | date_time           | date                |   buy_dom |   _buy_aggression |   _buy_aggression_pivot |   mfe_long_return |   mae_long_return |
|-----|---------------------|---------------------|-----------|-------------------|-------------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
| 113 | 2021-11-29 04:00:49 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |          16172.75 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 114 | 2021-11-29 04:05:34 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 115 | 2021-11-29 04:11:48 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 116 | 2021-11-29 04:19:01 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |             33.25 |               nan |
| 117 | 2021-11-29 04:24:22 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 118 | 2021-11-29 04:30:13 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 119 | 2021-11-29 04:36:14 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 120 | 2021-11-29 04:41:02 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 121 | 2021-11-29 04:51:20 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 122 | 2021-11-29 04:56:33 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 123 | 2021-11-29 05:02:13 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 124 | 2021-11-29 05:08:20 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 125 | 2021-11-29 05:17:34 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |            -15.00 |
| 126 | 2021-11-29 05:25:33 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 127 | 2021-11-29 05:33:10 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 128 | 2021-11-29 05:45:45 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
| 129 | 2021-11-29 05:55:03 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 |  16172.75 |              0.00 |                16172.75 |            nan    |               nan |
```

Comment: There is no `buy_dom` column in your example data?

Comment: @BeRT2me thanks for pointing that out, buy_dom  is the same as _buy_aggression_pivot.   Updated to reflect

Comment: Pasting your data with `|-----|-` everywhere makes it very difficult to copy/paste with something like `pd.read_clipboard`. Can you put it in an easier format to use?